# Retrieving blade/chassis (HP C7k) information from within the host through IPMI

Tags: hp, ipmi, ipmitool, blade-chassis

On an HP C7000 blade enclosure with standard DL385's with up to date ILO2 (2.29); local (and remote) IPMI works splendidly for getting the usual temperatures, mac addresses, access to the console; boot options, power and so on.

However I'd like to get access to the 'BladeCenter' information of the ILO (the last tab in the webinterface) from within the blade/host through IPMI (as opposed to doing an ssh query 'around through the outside' to the ILO or OA Eand extracting it from the XML).

Specifically I would like to learn what bay the blade is in (and perhaps the asset tags and enclosure/rack-name set in the OTA).

Not been able to find it through IPMI (IPMITool, OpenIPMI). Suggestions very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If we're doing this on a local host, then why use IPMI at all? While you certainly could use that to get chassis information, `dmidecode` is effective when on a local host. Specifically, the command `# dmidecode -t 3` will output (usually) all relevant chassis information while excluding other details.

Comment: Right - the puzzle I have is that 'dmidecode' does not seem to give me the blade slot.

Answer (score 0):

You should use HP-specifc tools. 

You could SSH to the Onboard Administrator and retrieve this info, for example.

Comment: That works perfectly fine - but I'd like to make the blades boot cycle (during which they are relatively untrusted; as the TPM is not yet fully configured) to not require some sort of credential that is allowed access to the OA. I.e. keep the need for a (trusted) network as minimal as I can.